# Delphi - Get IP of device using MAC address

Tags: delphi, networking, arp

How can I get the IP address of a device on my network from its MAC address using Delphi?

I been searching for days but can only find examples where you find the MAC address of a known IP.

I've tried sending an ARP request using a UDP client in Delphi without success. The broadcast prepends additional information which does not correlate with the ARP packet structure and therefore it is not being "seen" as an ARP request.

Below is an ARP request from the router:

[image]

And the "ARP" request from my Delphi program:

[image]

I'm not restricted to Delphi and can use C or C# but would prefer to use Delphi.

Comment: ARP protocol is just the reverse of what you are trying to do. With ARP, you request the (unknown) MAC address for a (known) IP address.The RARP protocol, now obsolete, once was able to retrieve the MAC address of some IP device, but the MAC<->IP couple must be known else where. RARP has been superseded by BOOTP and DHCP protocols.

Comment: If the target device you know the MAC address already communicated with the computer running your program, you can interrogate the local ARP table with command line ARP utility (you can run it from Delphi) or using the Windows IpHlpApi function  GetIpNetTable.

Comment: The device is unknown. It is acting as a server and I would like to connect to its server. But before I can connect to it, I need to know its IP address.

Comment: Another approach is you scan all IP addresses on your LAN (Easy for a class C segment, time consuming for class B segment). To scan, just try to establish a TCP connection. If the IP is responding, you'll find it in the ARP table I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I thought about scanning the IP range but would like to try and avoid that.

Comment: If the server is able to respond to an UDP broadcast, you can send a broadcast to the port (You must know it of course). Which kind of server do you want to reach?

Comment: Currently it is a TCP server, but I could configure a UDP server for this negotitiation process. Not a bad idea. The port will be constant and known.

Comment: From your last comment, I understand that you wrote the server program. You should have said that since the beginning! You can simply modify it so that it listen to a given UDP port and you client application broadcast a UDP datagram to request the IP. The server will answer (you write the code for that) with his IP address. Another possibility is that your server broadcast a UDP datagram which advertise about his presence. Broadcast done at startup and on a regular basic (once every 5 sec for example). Your client simply listen for the broadcast.

Comment: How did you learn the MAC address? For most TCP/IP traffic on an Ethernet network the same packet you would get a MAC address from also contains the IP address.

Comment: The MAC address is known during manufacturing. The IP address is variable since it is dynamic. I've decided to implement SDDP with UPnP.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from @fpiette, I learned that ARP is the inverse of what I need and what I actually need is RARP (Reverse ARP). But RARP seems to be obsolete.

ARP gives you the MAC associated with an IP. RARP gives you the IP associated with a MAC.

So I've decided to implement a form of SDDP with UPnP. UDP broadcasting.